# What files needs to be customized during the building process when i'm targeting a specific device / platform in Android?

Tags: android, build, android-source

I can't find a clear list of what files needs developer's attention when i'm building a new Android image.

All the guides that i have found until now are way too generic or really old.

I'm supposing that i'm not interested on customize the platform, i just want a vanilla flavour but for my device only.

Comment: Are you building an application, or building Android itself?

Comment: i'm trying to build Android from the official android repository

Comment: On most devices, that won't actually generate something very usable, due to missing device-specific proprietary extensions for the radios, graphics, etc.  You may want to track down an existing project that aims to build a usable image for your particular device.

Comment: @ChrisStratton not a practicable solution, too big and too much work, there also many files that are simply redundant; supposing that i have this specs, where i have to write them? this is what i'm asking.

Comment: If your attitude is based on feeling that looking at an example which has worked out the _undocumented_ solutions to the key challenges is "too big and too much work" I recommend you not tackle this project as your chances of success are very low.

Comment: @ChrisStratton my attitude is about working less for more, and working for something real not for pointless checkout, i'm not a lazy person, if i'm telling you that most of repos that i checked are basically a mirror of the original AOSP sourcecode with some small variations, this means that i have checked those repos. Also doing this i can't answer my own question simply because i'm just seeing something that others have done in a particular way and not necessarily in the right way. **continue**

Comment: It's like looking to millions line of code of Java to learn Java from scratch without asking for the basic rules of the language, just does not make any sense for a sane person.

Comment: It's as much about reading their build procedure as it is about specific changes to the kernel/configuration, vendor directory, etc.  Or maybe you don't need to generate a usable result, in which case you can follow the AOSP directions.  There use to be an android porting guide, it's not longer on the official site but is mirrored somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is a bit complicated. You probably **cannot** build a vanilla Android for your device, unless your device is one of the google developer phones. [Here is a list of the devices you can build Android for](http://source.android.com/source/building-devices.html). The reason being that the manufactures usually does not publish all the parts needed to actually build Android for their devices.

But do have a look at the [cyanogenmod project](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/), and [see if they support your device](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/devices). They are kind of trying to make a "vanilla" android source for the devices which the manufactures themselves does not support. And they are doing quite a nice job, in my opinion. I have a custom build of Android 4.0 for my Galaxy SII running for months now, and it is working perfectly fine.

If you update your questions with the devices your are using, I can probably provide specifics on how you can build cyanogenmod for your specific device.

Answer (score -1):

What are you trying to do ? 
Declare some images or layout specific to only one device ?

You can't do it with a selector on a folder (-large, -fr, ...), but with some code. Check this out : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#MODEL,

Comment: i have the source code, i want to build something for my device, i'm not interested on labels, i'm interested about configuration files usefull for the build process.